# Click doesn't trigger event written in an external jQuery file

Tags: jquery

Html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <div id="clickem">click me</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
$("#clickem").click(function() {
    alert("I was clicked.");
});
```

umm...so when I am doing it nothing is happening.

Comment: You can use the DOM ready event, *or* put your script include last in the body, which is starting to become more and more prevalent.

Comment: 5 of the same answer should probably help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#clickem").click(function() {
     alert("I was clicked.");
 });
});
```

wrap your code inside `document.ready`.

Comment: I still remember :3...actually i needed to wait 5 more mins so i couldint accept at that time

Answer (score 1):

Use the DOM ready event:

```
$(function(){
    $("#clickem").click(function() {
        alert("I was clicked.");
    });
});
```

`<div id="clickem">click me</div>` isn't rendered yet when you query the DOM.
When you send a function to the jQuery "constructor" it will execute it when the DOM will be ready.

`$( function() { });` is equivalent to `$(document).ready( function() { });`.
So, both of them can be used.

Comment: A little explanation will help improving your answer.

Comment: Done. Deleted that crap stuff.

Answer (score 0):

> nothing is happening

because your click event is called before the DOM element is ready. so it won't be able to find the element with id `clickem`.
call your script inside ready function

```
$(function(){
   $("#clickem").click(function() {
     alert("I was clicked.");
   });
});
```

this will call your script  after DOM is ready so the click event, now will be able to find the element and hence alert it..

always recommned you to write your script inside ready function...

Answer (score 0):

You need set action on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#clickem").click(function() {
    alert("I was clicked.");
 });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because your `popup.js` file is running before the DOM has finished loading the elements.

Therefore the click event handler for the selector `#clickem` wouldn't have found any items.

By wrapping your event handler in [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function this will ensure the DOM has finished loading:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#clickem").click(function() {
       alert("I was clicked.");
   });
});
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XfFu8/*

Answer (score 0):

The #clickem is not present in the DOM when you bind the click event. Use `.on()` to bind an event to any `current or future` element of them `document`. In which case you don't need to use the `$(document).ready()`.

**popup.js**

```
var onClickEm = function() {
    alert("I was clicked.");
};

$(document).on('click', '#clickem', onClickEm);
```

Another option is to defer loading the javascript file.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js" defer></script>
        <div id="clickem">click me</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`Defer`, When present, specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.